# Programming the STM32L152C8u6

Tags: stm32, embedded, stm32f4, stm32f4-discovery

I want to program the STM32L152C8u6 unit but i don't know how.
Can I use the SWD interface on the STM32F4Discovery development board to program a STM32L152C8u6?

Comment: Do you have any circuit?

Comment: Possibly you can use the discovey.

Comment: yes. yes you can

Comment: The discovery and nucleo board documentation tells you how to do it.  What did you not understand when you read those documents?

Comment: you can use other swd interfaces as well ones on some of the cortex-m launchpads, there are cheap j-link clones on ebay for a few bucks, etc...combined with openocd or other software.  the stm32 parts also have a uart based bootloader that you can use with say an ftdi breakout board and a few dozen lines of software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as a programmer debugger. You just need to remove ST-LINK jumpers and use SWD connector to connect your micro.
[image]

You need to configure in the Cube (or bare register) SWD debug mode

[image]

And then connect GND to GND, SWCLK to PA14 and SWDIO to PA13 pin and NRST to NRST.

[image]